# How to use xul editor with javascript?

Tags: javascript, xul

I want to use the editor feature of XUL to save changes in a document and read from it on load (I am developing an extension)

```
//NotePad.xul
<editor id="edit" type="content" editortype="html" src="about:blank" flex="1"/>

//NotePad.js
function initEditor(){
var editor = document.getElementById("myEditor");
editor.contentDocument.designMode = 'on';
}
```

I tried Changing the `src` attribute to an html doc i have locally but it didnt work.

So what i actually wanna do is :

1. Get the text written in the editor (something like `.getAttribute('value')`, but i didnt find a way to do so)
2. Write to it from javascript (something like `setAttribute('value')`)

Thanks in advance, i am really stuck in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Complicating things myself using a lot of code i finally found it, and it is really dumb to be honest, well here is how it gets done :

to set text :

```
var editor = content.document.getElementById("myEditor");
editor.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML += "Whatever your text is";
```

and get text it is obvious :

```
editor.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML
```

to think that i spent a loooot of time in this is ...

well the `innerHTML` varies, it depends on what you gave to `editortype` either html or text, so in case the editortype is set to text in that case we should use innerText.